# How do I make a link hover all arear surrounded by a margin

Tags: hyperlink, hover

I made a div where there are links with the default hover but then I saw something like this and I wanted my div to be like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUWPU.png)

I tried to do it like this.
I expected it to be like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2glby.png)
But I didn't get it, it was working like default link hover

Answer (score 0):

Would you provide the code, so that we can see it, need to see the output. I don't have enough reputation so I need to ask in the answer tab only sorry about that.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kr0sm7 - this is what I was expecting to get

Comment: And send your code too? so that it can be easy to compare

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/1lgll9 - This is what I got whit the classes in center and like the img